# How to call a function in controller from view

Tags: angularjs

I want to call a function from my view which is

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Class Name</td>
      <td>UserName</td>
      <td>Start Date</td>
      <td>End Date</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr ng-repeat="student in students" ng-click="getStudent(student)">
    <td>{{student.studentName}}</td>
    <td>{{student.className}}</td>
    <td>{{userName(student.userId)}}</td>
    <td>{{student.startDate}}</td>
    <td>{{student.endDate}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I will get user id from the JSON object,
I want to get the name of the student by using user id with the following function in the controller

```
angular.module('studentApp.controllers').
        controller('StudentController', ['$scope', 'InitialDataModel',
            function ($scope, InitialDataModel) {
                $scope.userName = function (id) {
                    var userObject = {};
                    userObject = _.findWhere(InitialDataModel.getUserObject, { "userId": id });
                    return userObject.userName;
                }
            }
        ])
```

But I am getting an error

> Error: [$interpolate:interr]
>
> Can't interpolate{{userName.getUserNameByUserId(student.userId)}}
>
> TypeError: Object function (n){return n instanceof w?n:this instanceof w?(this._wrapped=n,void 0):new w(n)} has no method 'findWhere'

How to remove  this error?
Am I doing it in the right way?

Comment: try this <td>username(student.userId)</td>

Comment: Can you post a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/)? Does underscore work for you elsewhere in your app?

Comment: @marck Yes ,I do use underscore

Comment: Your error is not related to Angular it throw error because `_` is not an object but a function. What version of underscore you're using? Can you link to a file?

Comment: Thanks jcubic.Yes,the error is with findWhere and solved it with using where.findWhere is not working in my app